# Is Euler's totient sub-homogeneous of degree 1?

Tags: nt.number-theory

That is, is it true that the bound 
$$\phi(mn)\leq m\phi(n)$$ holds for all pairs of natural numbers $m$ and $n$?

It is true on average, in the sense that 
$$\sum_{mn=k}m\phi(mn)\leq\sum_{mn=k}mn\phi(n),$$ and it holds for every pair I have computed. If it does not hold, what is the smallest counter example?

Comment: Another way of seeing this: $\phi(mn)$ is the number of integers in $[1,mn]$ coprime to $mn$, while $m\phi(n)$ is the number of integers in $[1,mn]$ coprime to $n$.

Comment: Thanks, Anonymous. You can also use Euler's product to get it directly, which provides the exact ratio. This I noticed following Quid's answer below. I'd like to point out that my interest was in the not-so-obvious corollary, that $$\sup_{d|n}\frac{d}{\phi(d)}=\frac{n}{\phi(n).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that, since $\phi$ is a multiplicative arithmetic function, i.e. $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ for coprime $a,b$, and since $\phi(a) \le a$ for every $a$, it suffices to consider the problem for prime powers.

And $$\phi(p^k p^t) = p^{k+t-1}(p-1) = p^k (p^{t-1}(p-1))= p^k\phi(p^t).$$

Comment: @Kevin Smith: you are welcome!